# Form Submit Connection Unexpectedly Closed

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a form for a casting agency. They enter the information of the actors into the form and send the form. There are 120 pieces of data such as Pictures, Videos, Text fields, Dates and Numbers. When the employees submit the form, it gives a warning that the server closed the connection unexpectedly. There is no error in the logs. I could not find out what the error is. (The program is only for Turkish people. Since most Turkish developers do not speak English, I had to make the variable naming in Turkish. Please excuse me)

FORMDATABASE.php

```php
<?php
include("../connection.php");
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["auth"])){
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
// POST verilerini al
    $hakkinda = $_POST["hakkinda"];
    $isim = $_POST["isim"];
    $soyisim = $_POST["soyisim"];
    $tc = $_POST["tc"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $tel1 = $_POST["tel1"];
    $tel2 = $_POST["tel2"];
    $sehir = $_POST["sehir"];
    $adres = $_POST["adres"];
    $cinsiyet = $_POST["cinsiyet"];
    $bakiye = $_POST["bakiye"];
    $IBAN = $_POST["IBAN"];
    $model = isset($_POST["model"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $oyuncu = isset($_POST["oyuncu"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $dogumtarihi = $_POST["dogumtarihi"];
    $gozrengi = $_POST["gozrengi"];
    $sacrenk = $_POST["sacrenk"];
    $tenrenk = $_POST["tenrenk"];
    $kilo = $_POST["kilo"];
    $boy = $_POST["boy"];
    $gogusnumarasi = $_POST["gogusnumarasi"];
    $kalcanumarasi = $_POST["kalcanumarasi"];
    $belnumarasi = $_POST["belnumarasi"];
    $ayakkabinumarasi = $_POST["ayakkabinumarasi"];
    $takimelbisenumarasi = $_POST["takimelbisenumarasi"];
    $sacuzunlugu = $_POST["sacuzunlugu"];
    $sacstili = $_POST["sacstili"];
    $lens = isset($_POST["lens"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $dovmesayisi = $_POST["dovmesayisi"];
    $atbiniciligi = isset($_POST["atbiniciligi"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $kilicbecerisi = isset($_POST["kilicbecerisi"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $yaybecerisi = isset($_POST["yaybecerisi"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $motorsikletakrobasi = isset($_POST["motorsikletakrobasi"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $paten = isset($_POST["paten"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $buzpateni = isset($_POST["buzpateni"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $kaykay = isset($_POST["kaykay"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $parasut = isset($_POST["parasut"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $yuzme = isset($_POST["yuzme"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $dalgic = isset($_POST["dalgic"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $dans = isset($_POST["dans"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $enstruman = isset($_POST["enstruman"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $sarki = isset($_POST["sarki"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $resim = isset($_POST["resim"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $sorf = isset($_POST["sorf"]) ? 1 : 0;
// ! dogu formda bak
    $dogu = isset($_POST["dogu"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $tenis = isset($_POST["tenis"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $voleybol = isset($_POST["voleybol"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $basketbol = isset($_POST["basketbol"]) ? 1 : 0;
    // ! atesli formda bak
    $atesli = isset($_POST["atesli"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $yoga = isset($_POST["yoga"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $plates = isset($_POST["plates"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $trakya = isset($_POST["trakya"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $ekstrim = isset($_POST["ekstrim"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $pandomim = isset($_POST["pandomim"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $vokal = isset($_POST["vokal"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $futbol = isset($_POST["futbol"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $bisiklet = isset($_POST["bisiklet"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $taklit = isset($_POST["taklit"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $freeflight = isset($_POST["freeflight"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $boks = isset($_POST["boks"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $kickboks = isset($_POST["kickboks"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $gitar = isset($_POST["gitar"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $gurce = isset($_POST["gurce"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $ingilizce = isset($_POST["ingilizce"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $rusca = isset($_POST["rusca"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $arapca = isset($_POST["arapca"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $almanca = isset($_POST["almanca"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $fransizca = isset($_POST["fransizca"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $cince = isset($_POST["cince"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $direkdansi = isset($_POST["direkdansi"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $bale = isset($_POST["bale"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $caca = isset($_POST["caca"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $disco = isset($_POST["disco"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $salsa = isset($_POST["salsa"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $breakdance = isset($_POST["breakdance"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $turkhalkoyunu = isset($_POST["turkhalkoyunu"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $hiphop = isset($_POST["hiphop"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $lirik = isset($_POST["lirik"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $rumba = isset($_POST["rumba"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $samba = isset($_POST["samba"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $tango = isset($_POST["tango"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $vals = isset($_POST["vals"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $zeybek = isset($_POST["zeybek"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $zumba = isset($_POST["zumba"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $sirtaki = isset($_POST["sirtaki"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $roman = isset($_POST["roman"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $rock = isset($_POST["rock"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $bulundugusehir = isset($_POST["bulundugusehir"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $yurtici = isset($_POST["yurtici"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $yurtdisi = isset($_POST["yurtdisi"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $m = isset($_POST["m"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $a = isset($_POST["a"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $a1 = isset($_POST["a1"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $a2 = isset($_POST["a2"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $b = isset($_POST["b"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $b1 = isset($_POST["b1"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $be = isset($_POST["be"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $c = isset($_POST["c"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $c1 = isset($_POST["c1"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $c1e = isset($_POST["c1e"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $ce = isset($_POST["ce"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $d = isset($_POST["d"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $d1 = isset($_POST["d1"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $d1e = isset($_POST["d1e"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $de = isset($_POST["de"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $f = isset($_POST["f"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $tecrubesiz = isset($_POST["tecrubesiz"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $profesyonel = isset($_POST["profesyonel"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $amator = isset($_POST["amator"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $figuran = isset($_POST["figuran"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $oyunculukegitimi = $_POST["oyunculukegitimi"];
    $oyunculukdeneyimi = $_POST["oyunculukdeneyimi"];
    $biridigiuniversite = $_POST["biridigiuniversite"];
    $oynadigiprogramlar = $_POST["oynadigiprogramlar"];
    // Profil fotograflarini da ekle
    //// Profilephotos
    $uploads_dir = '../uploads/';

// Resim dosyaları
    $filesresim = array(); // Dosya adlarını saklamak için bir dizi oluşturun
    if (!empty($_FILES['filesresim']['name'])) {
        for ($i = 0, $iMax = count($_FILES['filesresim']['name']); $i < $iMax; $i++) {
            $file_ext = pathinfo($_FILES['filesresim']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $new_filename = time() . mt_rand(1, 9999999999) . '.' . $file_ext;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filesresim']['tmp_name'][$i], $uploads_dir . $new_filename);
            $filesresim[] = $new_filename; // Yüklenen dosya adını dizide saklayın
        }
    }

// Video dosyaları
    $filesvideo = array(); // Dosya adlarını saklamak için bir dizi oluşturun
    if (!empty($_FILES['filesvideo']['name'])) {
        for ($i = 0, $iMax = count($_FILES['filesvideo']['name']); $i < $iMax; $i++) {
            $file_ext = pathinfo($_FILES['filesvideo']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $new_filename = time() . mt_rand(1, 9999999999) . '.' . $file_ext;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filesvideo']['tmp_name'][$i], $uploads_dir . $new_filename);
            $filesvideo[] = $new_filename; // Yüklenen dosya adını dizide saklayın
        }
    }

// Profil fotoğrafları
    $profilephotos = array(); // Dosya adlarını saklamak için bir dizi oluşturun
    if (!empty($_FILES['profilephoto']['name'])) {
        for ($i = 0, $iMax = count($_FILES['profilephoto']['name']); $i < $iMax; $i++) {
            $file_ext = pathinfo($_FILES['profilephoto']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $new_filename = time() . mt_rand(1, 9999999999) . '.' . $file_ext;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profilephoto']['tmp_name'][$i], $uploads_dir . $new_filename);
            $profilephotos[] = $new_filename; // Yüklenen dosya adını dizide saklayın
        }
    }

// Resim dosyalarını veritabanına kaydetme
    $resim_names_str = implode(',', $filesresim);

// Video dosyalarını veritabanına kaydetme
    $video_names_str = implode(',', $filesvideo);

// Profil fotoğraflarını veritabanına kaydetme
    $profil_names_str = implode(',', $profilephotos);
    global $pdoconn;
    $sqlinsert = $pdoconn->prepare("INSERT INTO `uyeler`  
    (
    `hakkinda`,    
    `isim`,    
    `soyisim`,    
    `tc`,    
    `email`,    
    `tel1`,    
    `tel2`,    
    `sehir`,    
    `adres`,    
    `cinsiyet`,   
    `bakiye`,  
    `IBAN`, 
    `model`,  
    `oyuncu`,   
    `dogumtarihi`, 
    `gozrengi`,  
    `sacrenk`,   
    `tenrenk`,   
    `kilo`,    
    `boy`,   
    `gogusnumarasi`, 
    `kalcanumarasi`,  
    `belnumarasi`,  
    `ayakkabinumarasi`, 
    `takimelbisenumarasi`, 
    `sacuzunlugu`,   
    `sacstili`,  
    `lens`, 
    `dovmesayisi`,  
    `atbiniciligi`,  
    `kilicbecerisi`,  
    `yaybecerisi`,  
    `motorsikletakrobasi`, 
    `paten`,  
    `buzpateni`,   
    `kaykay`,  
    `parasut`, 
    `yuzme`,  
    `dalgic`,  
    `dans`,  
    `enstruman`,  
    `sarki`, 
    `resim`,  
    `sorf`,  
    `dogu`,  
    `tenis`,   
    `voleybol`,  
    `basketbol`, 
    `atesli`,  
    `yoga`,  
    `plates`,  
    `trakya`, 
    `ekstrim`, 
    `pandomim`,  
    `vokal`,  
    `futbol`, 
    `bisiklet`,   
    `taklit`,  
    `freeflight`, 
    `boks`,  
    `kickboks`,  
    `gitar`,   
    `gurce`, 
    `ingilizce`, 
    `rusca`, 
    `arapca`,  
    `almanca`,  
    `fransizca`,   
    `cince`, 
    `direkdansi`, 
    `bale`, 
    `caca`,   
    `disco`,  
    `salsa`,   
    `breakdance`, 
    `turkhalkoyunu`, 
    `hiphop`,   
    `lirik`,  
    `rumba`,  
    `samba`,   
    `tango`,  
    `vals`,   
    `zeybek`, 
    `zumba`,  
    `sirtaki`,
    `roman`,   
    `rock`,    
    `bulundugusehir`,
    `yurtici`, 
    `yurtdisi`, 
    `m`,  
    `a`,  
    `a1`, 
    `a2`, 
    `b`,  
    `b1`, 
    `be`,  
    `c`,  
    `c1`, 
    `c1e`,  
    `ce`, 
    `d`,  
    `d1`, 
    `d1e`, 
    `de`,  
    `f`,  
    `tecrubesiz`,  
    `profesyonel`,   
    `amator`,   
    `figuran`, 
    `oyunculukegitimi`,  
    `oyunculukdeneyimi`, 
    `biridigiuniversite`,
    `oynadigiprogramlar`,
    `profilephotosarray`,
    `filesvideo`,
    `filesresim`
     )    VALUES (    
    ?, 
    ?, 
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?,   
    ?, 
    ?, 
    ?, 
    ?,  
    ?, 
    ?,  
    ?, 
    ?,   
    ?,  
    ?, 
    ?, 
    ?, 
    ?, 
    ?,  
    ?, 
    ?, 
    ?,  
    ?, 
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?, 
    ?, 
    ?,  
    ?, 
    ?, 
    ?, 
    ?, 
    ?,   
    ?,  
    ?, 
    ?, 
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?, 
    ?,   
    ?, 
    ?, 
    ?,   
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?,   
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?, 
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?, 
    ?,  
    ?, 
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?, 
    ?,   
    ?, 
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?, 
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?, 
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?, 
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?, 
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?,    
    ?, 
    ?, 
    ?,   
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?, 
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?, 
    ?,
    ?, 
    ?, 
    ?, 
    ?,
    ?,  
    ?, 
    ?,   
    ?, 
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?,   
    ?,
    ?
    )");

    $values = array(
        $hakkinda,
        $isim,
        $soyisim,
        $tc,
        $email,
        $tel1,
        $tel2,
        $sehir,
        $adres,
        $cinsiyet,
        $bakiye,
        $IBAN,
        $model,
        $oyuncu,
        $dogumtarihi,
        $gozrengi,
        $sacrenk,
        $tenrenk,
        $kilo,
        $boy,
        $gogusnumarasi,
        $kalcanumarasi,
        $belnumarasi,
        $ayakkabinumarasi,
        $takimelbisenumarasi,
        $sacuzunlugu,
        $sacstili,
        $lens,
        $dovmesayisi,
        $atbiniciligi,
        $kilicbecerisi,
        $yaybecerisi,
        $motorsikletakrobasi,
        $paten,
        $buzpateni,
        $kaykay,
        $parasut,
        $yuzme,
        $dalgic,
        $dans,
        $enstruman,
        $sarki,
        $resim,
        $sorf,
        $dogu,
        $tenis,
        $voleybol,
        $basketbol,
        $atesli,
        $yoga,
        $plates,
        $trakya,
        $ekstrim,
        $pandomim,
        $vokal,
        $futbol,
        $bisiklet,
        $taklit,
        $freeflight,
        $boks,
        $kickboks,
        $gitar,
        $gurce,
        $ingilizce,
        $rusca,
        $arapca,
        $almanca,
        $fransizca,
        $cince,
        $direkdansi,
        $bale,
        $caca,
        $disco,
        $salsa,
        $breakdance,
        $turkhalkoyunu,
        $hiphop,
        $lirik,
        $rumba,
        $samba,
        $tango,
        $vals,
        $zeybek,
        $zumba,
        $sirtaki,
        $roman,
        $rock,
        $bulundugusehir,
        $yurtici,
        $yurtdisi,
        $m,
        $a,
        $a1,
        $a2,
        $b,
        $b1,
        $be,
        $c,
        $c1,
        $c1e,
        $ce,
        $d,
        $d1,
        $d1e,
        $de,
        $f,
        $tecrubesiz,
        $profesyonel,
        $amator,
        $figuran,
        $oyunculukegitimi,
        $oyunculukdeneyimi,
        $biridigiuniversite,
        $oynadigiprogramlar,
        $profil_names_str,
        $video_names_str,
        $resim_names_str
    );

    // Değerleri sorguya bağlayın
    foreach($values as $key => $value) {
        $sqlinsert->bindValue(($key + 1), $value);
    }
    // Sorguyu çalıştırın
    $sqlinsert->execute();
}
if($sqlinsert) {
    echo "Kayıt başarıyla eklendi.";
} else {
    echo "Hata: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
if($_SESSION["id"]){
    header("Location: ../admin/index.php");
} else {
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}
```

I aim to transfer the data in the form to the database.

Comment: How many files and videos are you uploading at once? How long does the connection take before it closes?

Comment: @aynber I don't load it, agency employees do. The page stays in loading status for 5-6 seconds and then they get the error I mentioned.

Comment: Have you actually tried it yourself, or just relied on what the agency employees say? I would recommend testing it yourself, see what error it gives, and see if you can try to figure out where it's stopping.

Comment: @aynber I have tested it myself, but no matter which file I upload, I get the same error. Despite uploading the same information and files, nothing changes.

Comment: Is this a problem of uploading a file or of inserting the data into the database?

Comment: I think it might be a file upload problem but I don't know how to solve it. I don't have any other idea to explain why it gives me an error even though I filled the same file and the same information. I guess I will have to add a loading screen when uploading the file, but I have no idea how to do it.